# How does "or" work in variable assignments?

Tags: python, variables, operators

How does this work? Where is documentation?

```
a = 0 or "" or None or 2
print(a)

a = 2 or "" or None or 0
print(a)
```

Comment: A little experimentation with the interpreter and you can quickly determine how it works.

Comment: In both cases it returns the first "non-false" value it encounters and returns.  In the first case 0, empty string, and None all are essentially equivalent to false, so 2 is the answer.  In the second case, it encounters 2, which does not equate to false, and returns before checking the rest of the values.  Pretty straightforward.  Docs are here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/boolean.html

Answer (score 1):

Think of the `or` operator as a function:

```
or(x, y):
    if x:
        return x
    else:
        return y
```

Then `a = 0 or ""` will be the same as `a = or(0, "")`. Since `0` evaluates to `False`, this will return `""`.

Now, `a = 0 or "" or None or 2` is essentially

```
a = or(or(or(0, ""), None) 2)
```

The innermost `or` will return `""`, the next one will realize that `""` still evaluates to False and return `None`, and the outermost will finally return `2`.